# Multithreaded FlowDocument

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, mvvm, richtextbox

i get exception when i run the FlowDoc in separate thread,even using the dispatcher invok the problem cannot be solved.
i read some articles about serializing the flowdoc into xdoc and serialize back but its sounds like trouble.
i have been with this problem for 2 days and my head is cracked, please help :)

here is my code behind

```
 new Thread(() =>
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                 mcFlowDoc = new FlowDocument();
                 // Create a paragraph with text
                 Paragraph para = new Paragraph();
                 para.Inlines.Add(new Bold(new Run("This is a Title \n")));
                 para.Inlines.Add(new Run("I am a flow document. Would you like to edit me? \n"));

                 Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
                 {
                    mcFlowDoc.Blocks.Add(para);
                 }));
            }
        }).Start();
```

and comes my XAML, which i just use a normal RichTextBox and bound the flowdoc to  the Document property :

```
<fsrtb:FsRichTextBox x:Name="EditBox" Document="{Binding mcFlowDoc}" Grid.Row="0" Margin="10,10,10,91" ToolbarBackground="#FFD2CB84" ToolbarBorderBrush="#FFC6BE75" ToolbarBorderThickness="1,1,1,0" CodeControlsVisibility="Collapsed" />
```

Thank you.

Comment: All document elements (like FlowDocument or Paragraph) are derived from DispatcherObject and hence have thread affinity. They can't be accessed outside the thread in which they were created. In other words, all these elements have to created and modified in the UI thread, i.e. where the RichTextBox was created.

Comment: What is the exact exception you get?

Comment: Also note that `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` creates a new Dispatcher for your Thread, which is not the Dispatcher of the UI thread of your application. However, even with `Application.Current.Dispatcher`, your code won't work.

Comment: @Clemens Thank you for your reply, i know this, thats why i come here asking for a work arround :)

Comment: There is none. Do not create document elements in a background thread. If you have time-consuming operations to create the document content, use async/await, but create document elements in the UI thread.

Comment: @Clemens ow ! thats really bad ! what is the alternative for documents i should use ?

Comment: I think the real question here is why you're trying to do this in a separate thread in the first place? I feel there's some other piece of the puzzle you're not telling us.

Comment: @MarkFeldman thank you for your interest, this RTB will be updated from a ViewModel approximatly each second, and should display data depend on the results (text in red, green, gray, bold...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, well the bad news is RTB doesn't directly support data binding. There's a page somewhere on the MSDN site that explains why they did this but either way it was a deliberate design decision.

As far as I'm aware you have two options. The first is to roll your own solution. This basically involves creating view models for all the item types you want to display, maintaining a collection of them in your view model and using a behavior to bind to it and populate the RTB. Your behavior would also have to set up the bindings manually, i.e. instead of this:

```
para.Inlines.Add(new Bold(new Run("This is a Title \n")));
```

...you would instead do something like this:

```
var binding = new Binding
{
    Path = new PropertyPath("BackgroundProperty"),
    Mode = BindingMode.OneWay,
    UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged
    };
var run = new Run();
BindingOperations.SetBinding(run, Run.TextProperty, binding);
para.Inlines.Add(new Bold(run));
```

...which in this case adds a binding for the text property. I imagine this could be greatly simplified by using DataTemplates to specify the controls to use for each view model element and specify the bindings in XAML etc. If implemented correctly this would allow you create the document itself in the GUI thread once at load time but then allow you to update the view model properties for text, color etc in any thread you like without having to recreate the entire document.

The second option is to use a library where someone else has already done this work for you, and for that I would recommend you have a look at the [WPF Tookkit's implementation of a bindable RichTextBox](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/wiki/RichTextBox).

Comment: Thank you so much, i have used the Toolkit and it works fine. i also made it work by samply wrappingthe entir doc creation inside a dispatcher.Invok ! i don't know if this is the right way but it works !